# Why is this react-hot-loader not working I get error about loaders when they call rules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I followed this [how-to-add-hot-module-reloading-to-a-react-app](https://developerhandbook.com/webpack/how-to-add-hot-module-reloading-to-a-react-app/) but get an error.

I know this is an easy one because i'm new to this. Also most tutorials are so out of date so its hard to find something consistent to learn this

I think the webpack server is ok and can be started ok
Please advice:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import App from "./App";
|
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here's webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: port,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true
  }
};
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**UPDATE**
Adding App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./components/structure/Header";
import Content from "./components/structure/Content";
import Footer from "./components/structure/Footer";
import Resume from "./resume.json";
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = [
      Resume.basics.name,
      Resume.basics.label,
      [Resume.basics.location.region, Resume.basics.location.country].join(", ")
    ].join(" | ");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Content />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default hot(App)
```

Also get this error now .babelrc cant find schema:

[image: ssss]

Comment: Are you getting this error after adding `import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'` as per tutorial?

Comment: I get the error when I run the app in Vcode. Webpack server seems to work Project is running at http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Added  App.js to my Q.

Comment: `Unexpected token (5:16)` - seems issue with JSON file loading. (App.js)